# Interaction between controller and model

Tags: php, yii, argument-passing

Let's say I have two controllers and two models

```
Controller_1 and it's model: Model_1
Controller_2 and it's model: Model_2
```

Is it ok Controller_1 call a method from Model_2 or it should call Controller_2 and THEN this one calls that method in Model_2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any controller can call any model if it can create the object of particular model. In Yii one model is for one table not for one controller. But we can use multiple tables in a single model.